# Run gcc with QProcess in QT5

Tags: c++, gcc, qt5

I need to compile a source from a first program.
I need to run this:

```
gcc -o finalOutput sources/main.cpp sources/config.h -lcurl '-DHOST=(char*)"https://google.fr/"'
```

I use QT5, here is what I tested:

```
QProcess *proc;  
proc = new QProcess();  
proc->start("gcc -o finalOutput sources/main.cpp sources/config.h -lcurl '-DHOST=(char*)"https://google.fr/"'"); // start program
ui->lblReturn->setText("ok");
```

The problem comes from the syntax of the gcc command, this part:
`'-DHOST=(char*)"https://google.fr/"'`

[image: QT5]

I do not understand how to format correctly

Comment: You need to escape the `"` characters using `\"`, so use `...(char*)\"https://google.fr/\"'");` instead of `...(char*)"https://google.fr/"'");`*.

Comment: @pschill this solves the syntax problem but the command does not execute correctly and no compilation is performed :/

Comment: The `QProcess::start` function has and overload which takes one argument for the program name and a `QStringList` for the arguments. Try using `QStringList args = QStringList() << "-o" << "finalOutput" << "sources/main.cpp" << [...]; proc->start("gcc", args);`.

Comment: @pschill yeaaah!! here is the command that works perfectly! (creation of the executable and adding the variable host): `QStringList args = QStringList() << "-o" << "finalOutput" << "sources/main.cpp" << "sources/config.h" << "-lcurl" << "-DHOST=(char*)\"https://google.fr/\"";` You can create an answer, I would accept it =) thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QProcess::start` function has several overloads. The first version

```
QProcess::start(const QString& command, OpenMode mode=ReadWrite);
```

has a strange behavior with arguments that contain quote characters. To cite the documentation:

> Literal quotes in the command string are represented by triple quotes.

That's why I usually recommend the

```
QProcess::start(const QString& program, const QStringList& arguments, OpenMode mode=ReadWrite);
```

overload. Using this, the command

```
gcc -o finalOutput sources/main.cpp sources/config.h -lcurl '-DHOST=(char*)"https://google.fr/"'
```

can be executed with the following code:

```
QStringList args = QStringList()
    << "-o"
    << "finalOutput"
    << "sources/main.cpp"
    << "sources/config.h"
    << "-lcurl"
    << "-DHOST=(char*)\"https://google.fr/\"";
QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
proc->start("gcc", args);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)